# Regular expression to exclude a particular number

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a Model called Department.

```
    class Department < ActiveRecord::Base  
      # Associations
      belongs_to :client
      belongs_to :facility

      scope :facility_departments, ->(facility_id) { 
                                  where("facility_id = ? ", facility_id)}

      scope :matching_departments, ->(facility_id, identifier) {facility_departments(facility_id).where("
 ? REGEXP reg_exp ", identifier.to_s).order("weight DESC") }

    end
```

- In the departments table I have a `facility_id`, and a regular expression column.
- I also have employees in my application, each one having a department id. In order to identify an employees department, I'm using scope `matching_departments` in department model (see above).
- Each employee has  got an identifier too.
- All employees having a numeric identifier and identifier length = 9 , except 9 zeros (000000000) - should map to department 1.

So what should be the regular expression for `department-1` in my `departments` table? 
I updated it with `(^[0-9]{9,}$)` - matching all numeric identifiers with `length 9`. How can I exclude `9 zeros`?

Comment: So, you ask for a MySQL REGEXP pattern? It does not seem to support any lookarounds. You can use `WHERE col REGEXP '^[0-9]{9}$ AND col <> '000000000'`

Comment: Are You saying to save `^[0-9]{9}$ AND col <> 000000000`  in database ? or to change the query like this. I didn't get you. In my case col is a dynamic value. It is one argument to my scope. It will vary on each call to scope. So I don't think this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty, but should work with even the simplest regex flavor. Make 9 separate tests that checks for a non 0 digit in each position:

```
^(?:[1-9]\d{8}|\d[1-9]\d{7}|\d{2}[1-9]\d{6}|\d{3}[1-9]\d{5}|\d{4}[1-9]\d{4}|\d{5}[1-9]\d{3}|\d{6}[1-9]\d{2}|\d{7}[1-9]\d|\d{8}[1-9])$
```

First test for 1-9 in the first position followed by 8 digits. The next for a digit followed by a 1-9 which in turn is followed by 7 digits. And so on...

If your regex flavor doesn't support the digit character class, replace `\d` with `[0-9]`.

Hope this works for you.

Regards

**Edit:**
It might even be that non capturing groups aren't supported so replace that with an ordinary capture group:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{8}|[0-9][1-9][0-9]{7}|[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{3}[1-9][0-9]{5}|[0-9]{4}[1-9][0-9]{4}|[0-9]{5}[1-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{6}[1-9][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{7}[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]{8}[1-9])$
```